# How to open a link in new tab using angular?

Tags: html, angular, routes, anchor

I have an angular 5 component that needs to open a link in new tab, I tried the following:

```
<a href="www.example.com" target="_blank">page link</a>
```

when I open the link, the application gets slow and opens a route like:

```
localhost:4200/www.example.com
```

My question is:
What is the correct way to do this in angular?

Comment: This works for me `<a href="//example.com" target="_blank">page link</a>`

Comment: You could just use `<a [href]="'www.example.com'" target="_blank">Link</a>`

Answer (score 298):

Use `window.open()`. It's pretty straightforward !

In your `component.html` file:

```
<a (click)="goToLink('www.example.com')">page link</a>
```

You may have to add the `http` prefix if it doesn't redirect correctly:

```
<a (click)="goToLink('http://www.example.com')">page link</a>
```

In your `component.ts` file:

```
goToLink(url: string){
    window.open(url, "_blank");
}
```

Comment: Can someone point out a way of doing this where the string within the goToLink function isn't a 'magic string'? For instance, through a variable?

Comment: @BrianAllanWest I would just set a variable in the corresponding component file and leave the parameter out in the html. If this doesn't work, just bind it to the template using the default binding property [ ] and then you can run whatever logic you want on that. 

.html
goToLink()

.ts
goToLink() { window.open(Your Variable Here, "_blank") }

Comment: How can I let it be in a small popup window, and listen to changes in its URL.

Comment: I would add a `href=''`, so it stills looks clickable

Comment: May use without *_blank*. By default, a new tab opens.

Answer (score 86):

just use the full url as href like this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank">page link</a>
```

Comment: this is the simplest way.

Comment: Appreciate this answer. Clean and simple.

Answer (score 43):

I have just discovered an alternative way of opening a new tab with the Router.

On your template,

```
<a (click)="openNewTab()" >page link</a>
```

And on your component.ts, you can use serializeUrl to convert the route into a string, which can be used with `window.open()`

```
openNewTab() {
  const url = this.router.serializeUrl(
    this.router.createUrlTree(['/example'])
  );

  window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Very nice and handy in some cases. Just what I needed.

Comment: where do you get the router in this.router from? Like what is the import for router? Or is it angular core?

Comment: @Naga Import it like this `import { Router } from "@angular/router";`

Answer (score 36):

Just add `target="_blank"` to the

```
<a mat-raised-button target="_blank" [routerLink]="['/find-post/post', post.postID]"
    class="theme-btn bg-grey white-text mx-2 mb-2">
    Open in New Window
</a>
```

Comment: Literally just this, best answer

Answer (score 22):

```
<a [routerLink]="" (click)="openSite(SiteUrl)">{{SiteUrl}}</a>
```

and in your Component.ts

```
openSite(siteUrl) {
   window.open("//" + siteUrl, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: If using "//" + siteUrl then https:// or http:// should be committed in the siteUrl, maybe that was causing the issue for you @Nicolas

Comment: Here is other example bassed in your code. `downloadFile(){
    const filePath = 'assets/files';
    const fileName = '/myfile.xlsx';
    const url = `${filePath}${fileName}`;
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }`

Comment: From an accessibility standpoint should never have to add click to <a> tag, <a> should ALWAYS have an href attribute, buttons and links are not the same, both can be completely styled with CSS since IE9 which has long been retired... it's 2021 people

Answer (score 18):

Some browser may block popup created by `window.open(url, "_blank");`.
An alternative is to create a link and click on it.

```
...

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}
...

  openNewWindow(): void {
    const link = this.document.createElement('a');
    link.target = '_blank';
    link.href = 'http://www.your-url.com';
    link.click();
    link.remove();
  }
```

Comment: best answer. Safe and clean

Answer (score 13):

In the `app-routing.modules.ts` file:

```
{
    path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroComponent
}
```

In the `component.html` file:

```
target="_blank" [routerLink]="['/hero', '/sachin']"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 window.open(this.url+'/create-account')
```

No need to use `'_blank'`. `window.open` by default opens a link in a new tab.

Comment: Why should he try that? What does that do?

Comment: this is the answer of this question 
"How to open link in new tab in angular 5"
window.open  by default open link in new tab

Answer (score 2):

u can add https in your code and it works for me

```
goToLink(url: string) {
    window.open('https://' + url, "_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your component.html, Add this following html code

```
<a [routerLink]="" (click)="openSiteinNewTab()">click here to view</a>
```

In your component.ts, Add the following Typescript code

```
export class AppComponent {
  siteUrl = "stackoverflow.com";

  openSiteinNewTab() {
    window.open("//" + this.siteUrl, '_blank');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**you can try binding property whit route**

in your component.ts
`user:any = 'linkABC'`;

in your component.html
`<a target="_blank" href="yourtab/{{user}}">new tab </a>`