# Why does document.open send me to a blank page?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I want to open an external URL in a new tab from my Angular 8 SPA.

[Answers to other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52241406/3075190) suggest that you can use `window.open(url, "_blank")` to achieve this, and this works for me, but I am looking for something I can unit test.

Based on [an answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37521339/3075190), I have tried injecting the `Document` and calling `document.open(url, "_blank")` like so:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/common";

@Component( ........ )
export class MyClass implements OnInit {

  private externalLink = "https://bbc.co.uk";

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: Document) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public navigate() {
    this.document.open(this.externalLink, "_blank");
  }
}
```

However, when this runs the screen goes immediately white and nothing else happens. No errors are logged to the console and placing a breakpoint in the method shows that the document is injected correctly as far as I can tell.

If this can't be resolved I am tempted to wrap a service around `window.open()` and inject that.

Comment: Wrapping `window.open` in a service that can be mocked and spied is the way to go, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no other answers being given, I did as I suggested I might in my question. I wrapped a small service around `window.open` like so:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class NewTabService {

  constructor() { }

  public open(url: string, newTab: boolean = false) {
    if (newTab) {
      window.open(url, "_blank");
      return;
    }

    window.location.href = url;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the this code

```
window.open(this.externalLink, "_blank");
```

instead of

```
this.document.open(this.externalLink, "_blank");
```

Hope this will help!!!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open   visit it to understand.