# Open link in new tab not opening in new tab when using navigate in angular

Tags: angular

In HTML page

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="moreInfo(fashion)">{{fashion.postName}}</a></h2>
```

In Component.ts

```
moreInfo(data) {
    this.router.navigate(['/blog-info/', data.postName]);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open link in new tab in angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240123/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-in-angular-5)

Comment: No, because in that question user is using [routerLink] in html page. But I'm using this.router.navigate from component.

Comment: Yes, but `Router#navigate` is equivalent to the `routerLink` attribute.

Comment: Correct, but when I'm clicking on link it will call the```moreInfo()``` then it will navigate but When right click on link and want to open in new tab that time not working.

Comment: It's because you're using a click listener... It's not the same as using the `href` attribute.

Comment: Yes, So any solution for this or we have to use like that question?

Comment: Why are you not using the `routerLink` attribute anyways?

Comment: In routerLink we are passing the value that is the URL but by using navigate I'm replacing the some name for URL Like this ```this.router.navigate(['/blog-info/', (data.postName.replace(/\s/g, '-')) + '-' + data._id]);```

Comment: Yes, routerLink work but As I told I want to change some URL info

Comment: Every modification you do here you could simply make it inside routerlink [routerlink]="['blog-info', data.postName.replace(...)]"

Comment: I got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call function in routerLink. create function in component:

```
moreInfo(data) {
     return  data.postName.replace(/\s/g, '-') + '-' + data._id;
  }
```

Use like this in routerLink:

```
[routerLink]="['/blog-info', moreInfo(fashion)]"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add target attribute in your HTML

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><a target="_blank" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="moreInfo(fashion)">your template expression</a></h2>
```

Comment: This giving me in URL when right click for open in new tab about:blank#blocked

Comment: about:blank#blocked

Comment: Why are not you using window.open(link, '_blank');

Comment: Agree, but I don't want to open every time in new tab, Like if user want to open in new tab then only.

Comment: How do you differentiate when user want to open in a new tab or not?

Comment: It's simple when use right click on link and select Open link in new tab.

Comment: for example in the site, if you right click on post it will open in new tab other wise open in same page. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/

Comment: Don't you think it is by default behavior,

Comment: When we are calling function that time we are using javascript:void(0) because of this not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it, you should have `href` attribute. So, `routerLink` is a good choice. other way:

```html
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="/blog-info/{{fashion.postName}}" (click)="moreInfo($event, fashion)">{{fashion.postName}}</a></h2>
```

```js
moreInfo(event, data) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.router.navigate(['/blog-info/', data.postName]);
}
```