# How to XHR with Angular and have JavaScript functionality? Alternatives if that's impossible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, xmlhttprequest, angular-httpclient

I am using Angular for the frontend and node.js for the backend.

The problem is that in my Angular web app I want to open another web app, which uses JavaScript and only the noscript content gets printed out.

I want to accomplish so that in my Angular Web app when I fill out the required fields a popup window opens up which using XHR (HttpClient) opens up the other web app, which is written in Javascript+HTML5+CSS3.

How do I accomplish this? I already tried writing a component, which opens up the web app over XHR (HttpClient).

Comment: No, don't use xhr for this. Just load the other web app in an iframe, or better, separate tab.

Comment: Is using the Fetch API a good alternative?

Comment: No, don't use fetch for this either. Just load the other web app in an iframe, or better, separate tab.

Comment: For those looking for a good alternative take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240123/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-in-angular-5 this is way cleaner than using iframes in Angular