# Clicking on <a> tag with href attribute

Tags: html, angular

I wrote the following code :

```
<a target="_blank"  *ngIf="value.url" [href]="value.url">{{value.data  | translate | removeHTMLTags }}</a>
```

My expection is to open the new entity on the new tab.
I checked the value.url and is: `/#/inquiry/5452`

when i click on it, it seem not clickable.

At the inspect its looks:
[image]

what im doing wrong?

im using Angular 8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open link in new tab in angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52240123/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-in-angular-5)

Comment: Seems that you are binding href with invalid hyperlink! /#/inquiry/5452 will not open any hyperlink in new tab.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `/#/inquiry/5452` is not a valid `URL` and it expected a valid one. If you have a path like `/inquiry/:id` in your `app-routing.module.ts`, So use Angular [RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#routerlink).

You should create something like this:

```html
<a target="_blank"  *ngIf="value.url" [routerLink]="['inquiry', '5452']">{{value.data  | translate | removeHTMLTags }}</a>
```